# Which linux distros have GNOME as the default desktop manager?

Tags: gnome, distributions, desktop-environment

Where can I find which distros have GNOME as the default desktop manager? Personaly I don't need a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora, Debian, and a lot of Debian-based distros *(like Ubuntu, Linux Mint, OpenSuse)* have got GNOME as the default desktop manager.

Also, there is a list of the distributions with GNOME avalible on [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?desktop=GNOME).